# Write a mockito test for void method

Tags: java, junit, mockito, void

I am trying to write a test case for a method which is very badly written, below is implementation of the method:

```
public void processData(){
 DB.connectToDB1();
 List rawData = DB.getRawData();
 List processedData = new List(); 
 for (Object obj : rawData){
  //pass through filter
  if(obj.passesFilter){
   processedData.add(obj);
  }
 }
 DB.connectToDB2();
 DB.insertProcessedData(processedData);
}
```

I want to test if filter rules are working correctly, what approach should i take?

Comment: mock / spy `DB`, capture the parameters passed to `insertProcessedData` and then compare the recorded parameters to what you expect.

Comment: What you can do is use the `Mockito.verify` to check if you went through the filter method and the numbers of times you used it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mock `DB` and on `getRawData()` return the list of data, you want to be processed:

```
Mockito.when(DB.getRawData()).thenReturn(myList);
```

And then use `Mockito.verify` to check that all of the rawData that should pass the filter is in the list of `processedData`, by using a `Captor`, which can capture the the data passed to `insertProcessedData`:

```
@Captor
ArgumentCaptor<String> listCaptor;

Mockit.verify(DB).insertProcessedData(listCaptor.capture());
List<Object> processedData = listCaptor.getValue();
```

And then you can check `processedData` for whatever you need (e.g. expected size,...).